# Object of class Collection could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I didn't get the select option from controller 
it's my Edit page

```
{!! Form::select('channel_id',[''=>'Select A Channel'] + $channels,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Below is my Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $channels = Channel::all() ;

    $d = Discussion::findOrFail($id);

    return view('discussion.edit',compact('channels','d'));
}
```

Comment: Which properties of channel model do you need on the edit page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Form::select` is only meant to take a an array of key value pairs for setting the options.

What you can do is use the [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
[''=>'Select A Channel'] + $channels->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
```

or

```
$channels->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('Select A Channel', '')->toArray() // I'm not sure if you will need `->toArray()` here
```

---

If you're not going to be using the `$channels` for anything else on the page then you'll be able to use the `pluck()` in the controller instead:

```
$channels = Channel::pluck('name', 'id');
```

Then in your `blade` file you can do:

```
[''=>'Select A Channel'] + $channels->toArray()
```

or

```
$channels->prepend('Select A Channel', '')->toArray()
```

You will need to change the `name` and `id` placeholders I've used with `pluck()` to match the column names from your `channels` table.

Lastly, depending on the behaviour you want from the placeholder for your `<select>` you can actually set it by doing:

```
{!! Form::select('channel_id', $channels->pluck('name', 'id'), null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select A Channel']) !!}
```

Notice the `'placeholder' => 'Select A Channel']` in the last array:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#drop-down-lists